# Specifying custom ColorFunction for ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, color

I have some data that takes the shape  `{{x,y,z}...} = somedata`. I also have a custom gradient which I made using `Blend[{{0.4, RGBColor[1,1,1], {0.3, RGBColor[1,0.9, 0.6]}, {0.3,RGBColor[0,0.7,0.9]}}]`

I am trying to do the following,

```
ListPlot3D[data4, ColorFunction ->Blend[{{0.4, RGBColor[1,1,1], {0.3, RGBColor[1,0.9, 0.6]}, {0.3,RGBColor[0,0.7,0.9]}}], PlotLegends-> True, PlotRange -> {0,1}]
```

z-values should give the height, and I want the plot to be colored based on the height values, with the z = 0 being pure white. In a similar vein, I want to construct the following contour plot as well.

```
ListPlot3D[data4, ColorFunction ->Blend[{{0.4, RGBColor[1,1,1], {0.3, RGBColor[1,0.9, 0.6]}, {0.3,RGBColor[0,0.7,0.9]}}], PlotLegends-> True, PlotRange -> {0,1}]
```

I get correct looking shapes for my plot, but the colors aren't applied at all. I just get solid color plots. I suspect it is beccause `Blend[..]` needs to be converted to a function and then applied to the z-values of the data, but I am unsure if this is indeed the correct way to do it, and if it is, I am not very confident with the syntax to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If we want the z = 0 being pure white, I think we need to set `{0,White}` in the color settings.

```
SeedRandom[1]
data4 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 3}];
colorSettings = {{0., RGBColor[1, 1, 1]}, {0.2, 
   RGBColor[1, 0.9, 0.6]}, {0.5, RGBColor[0, 0.7, 0.9]}}
ListPlot3D[data4, ColorFunction -> (Blend[colorSettings, #3] &), 
 PlotLegends -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
 ClippingStyle -> None, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this seems like a good answer. thanks for the tip on setting {0, White}, and clearing up the syntax. for `(Blend[colorSettings, Abs@#3] &)`. This works for me for `ListPlot3D` but I get the following error `Function::slotn: Slot number 3 in Blend[col,Abs[#3]]& cannot be filled from (Blend[col,Abs[#3]]&)[0.].` when I try to use it with `ListContourPlot`. If you can comment on this issue, i can select this as the accepted answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @jcp Remove Abs@ and try it again.

Comment: @jcp Try this  `SeedRandom[1]; data4 = 
 RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 3}]; colorSettings = {{0., 
   RGBColor[1, 1, 1]}, {0.2, RGBColor[1, 0.9, 0.6]}, {0.5, 
   RGBColor[0, 0.7, 0.9]}}; ListPlot3D[data4, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Blend[colorSettings, z]], 
 PlotLegends -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
 ClippingStyle -> None, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]`

Comment: Ah the issue is still with `ListContourPlot[dummydata, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{p, q, r}, Blend[col, r]], 
 PlotLegends -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
 ClippingStyle -> None, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]`. with contour plot, i get `Function::fpct: Too many parameters in {p,q,r} to be filled from Function[{p,q,r},Blend[col,r]][0.].` `dummydata` has the same shape as `data4`, namely `dummydata = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 3}]`